# What does weight and sign (positive and negative) in the LINGAM DAG indicates?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am using LINGAM in python to build a DAG. The output is with the weight and edges.
How to interpret these edges?

I am assuming the sign says proportionality of the causality.
i.e if it is + it is closely related and - is lesser related.
[An example of DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCZUo.png)

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: You should check the documentation for your LINGAM implementation. I would guess that it corresponds to the direction of the effect, i.e., in your example graph, increasing x1 would decrease x5 with a strength of 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A positive edge from variable *x1* to variable *x2* implies a positive correlation between **changes** in variable *x1* and **changes** in variable *x2*. To put it differently, when *x1* goes up so does *x2*. The strength of the positive causal connection is revealed by the weight of the positive edge.

On the other side, the negative edge between variable *x1* and variable *x4* shows that **changes** in *x1* have a negative correlation with **changes** in *x4*. If *x1* increases, *x4* decreases or vice versa. Again, the weight of the negative edge corresponds to the intensity of the negative causal association.